# teams tab app - pass deeplink option like subEntityId to appInstallDialog when a user clicks on adaptive card button

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, microsoft-teams-js

Users from our teams tab app can share our app installation link in channel through graph api post request -> `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/${teamId}/channels/${channelId}/messages` so that other users from that organization can install our app. We're sending the message in channel via adaptive card. In the adaptive card, we added a button which will open app installation dialog if user clicks on it. In the deeplink parameter, we're assigning the referrer id to the subEntityId of the context object so that when a new user install our app, we can know who referred the app to him.

Now the problem is we're not getting the subEntityId from teams context when a new user clicks on the adaptive card button. Microsoft teams open the app installation dialog and after installation, it takes user to our tab app but the subEntityId becomes null.

This is how we're creating the adaptive card.

```
{
    "title": "I have just installed the Sample App.",
    "subtitle": "",
    "text": "<p style='line-height:175%'>Click on the below button to install the Sample                  App",
"buttons": [
    {
        "type": "openUrl",
        "title": "Try Sample App",
        "value": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/app_id/index?context=%7B%22subEntityId%22%3A%22referrlToken%3A%20633fd8ea2dbcfe23c7fa6322%22%7D"
    }    
 ]
}
```

Is it possible to pass the subEntityId from app installation dialog to the teams tab app after installation is finished?

Any kind of help is appreciated!

[image: adaptive card in channel]

[image: teams open this app install popup when user clicks on adaptive card]

Comment: Is it happening in MS Teams Desktop/Web client or in Mobile clients only?

Comment: It is not working in both desktop and mobile client. When user installs the app, it takes us to our tab app but we lost the subPageId which was assigned to deeplink.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Could you pls inform us if it is possible to pass subPageId from appInstallationDialog to tab or this feature not yet implemented in teams-js sdk?

Comment: We also tried to pass subPageId from appInstallationDialog, however facing the same issue. We are checking with engineering team if this is a bug or this feature is not implemented. We will inform you once we get any update from engineering team. Thanks!

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Thanks for the information. Can you suggest if there is any other way to track the referrer_id when a new user installs the app by clicking on the button from adaptive card? In our tab app, we need this feature urgently(currently teams app is inconsistent with what we've in web and zoom app.)

Comment: We got update from engineering team that "If anyone deep links to their app which is not yet installed, then after the app gets installed, we retry to route using the exact same deep link (so the subEntityId would get passed along)." Could you please try this in New Teams client and let us know if you are still facing this issue? There doesn't seem to be any other way to track the referrer_id when a new user installs the app by clicking on the button from adaptive card.